# Installing critical and security updates only on Windows Server 2019

Tags: azure, windows-update, windows-server-2019

We have used Linux `unattended-upgrades` package in the past to only install critical security updates on our machines automatically. On Linux, the file `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades` shows that by default, only security updates are installed (The other packages are commented out) :

```
// Automatically upgrade packages from these (origin:archive) pairs
Unattended-Upgrade::Allowed-Origins {
    "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-security";
//  "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-updates";
//  "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-proposed";
//  "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-backports";
};
```

We would like to do the same on our new Windows Server 2019 server on Azure, though from my online research it seems like this is not quite as easy to implement.

I've had a look at the Windows Update location in  **Local Group Policy** and can not see an entry for installing only critical security updates/bugfixes.

From what I can see, Microsoft is moving into a more cumulative approach when it comes to updates -- am I right in saying that 'cherry-picking' only security updates is a *bad* idea? Is it even possible with just group policy/registry?

I'm aware that some use WSUS to cherry-pick updates, and have been looking into **[Azure Update Management](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/automatic-vm-guest-patching)**  for automatic VM guest patching, but it is in preview at the moment and shouldn't be used for production servers.

What is best practice here? Ideally we want critical updates installed *immediately*, with any needed reboots delayed to a weekly maintenance window. I would rather not install feature updates. I'm aware that these can be deferred, but not disabled completely.

Comment: Are you looking to do this through some automated system or do you want to manually choose which updates to install? If you want to do it manually, try using "sconfig" in cmd and choose option 6, then choose R (recommended updates only), that should only give you the updates that are nessecary for running the OS.

Comment: I would prefer if this happens automatically, like Linux's unattended-upgrades package.

Comment: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-update-winpc/how-to-recieve-security-updates-only/58ef6035-607c-498c-b026-d1db63e3d327#:~:text=For%20receiving%20only%20security%20updates,%22Defer%20feature%20updates%22%20box.

If you change this setting, you should only get security updates. You can then configure  windows to install updates automatically. Both settings should also be able to be set through GPO

Comment: Thanks Martinos, but deferring only puts off installing feature updates to a later date, at max a year. They would still eventually be installed.

Comment: You are correct, i overlooked that part. The next best thing microsoft offers what i believe is LTSC : https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/get-started-19/servicing-channels-19

Maybe someone else has a better suggestion, though.